Blackscreen with Radeon + autologin doesn't work + random unable to fully shutdown
My system is Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1 with AMD Radeon 5600, fresh install, dual boot windows.
I have three issues:

Unable to boot with blackscreen.
Autologin doesn't work.
At random, unable to fully shut down or reboot.

I got black screen and Ubunt can't boot with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" in Grub.
Autologin is enabled in Lightdm.conf
Ubuntu boot successfully with autologin working properly, after boot to windows, then reboot to Ubuntu. This set is the only one with autologin working properly.
But, after reboot to Ubuntu from Ubuntu, or after a shutdown, Ubuntu can boot, but password is required at login, while autologin is set on, with one of this set in Grub file.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
During my tests, I cloned my system to a usb ssd drive. Same system, same grub, same machine, but drive different and autologin works.
I want Ubuntu to start up with autologin, how to do?
Recap like this:
If boot from USB SSD drive then
    Ubuntu start and autologin works (A)
Else #boot from nvme
    If boot with `splash` in Grub then  
        Blackscreen, Ubuntu doesn’t start (B)  
    Else  
        If boot with `nomodeset` in Grub then  
            Ubuntu start and autologin works (B)  
        Else  
            If reboot from windows then  
                Ubuntu start and autologin works (C)  
            Else  
                Ubuntu start and autologin doesn’t work (C)  
            End if  
        End if  
    End if
End if


In my opinion, results (B) come from kernel issue and (A,B) come from another cause to identify.
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/lightdm
$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=nicolas
autologin-user-timeout=0

System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT]
    vendor: Gigabyte driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: RDNA-1 bus-ID: 03:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: N/A
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: radeonsi,swrast platforms:
    active: x11,surfaceless,device inactive: gbm,wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: amd mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT (radeonsi
    navi10 LLVM 17.0.6 DRM 3.57 6.8.0-41-generic)

# kernels installed
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-41-generic                   6.8.0-41.41                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic                   6.8.0-44.44                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                            6.8.0-44.44                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image


When you boot and the grub menu is displayed is there any other kernel available you can load? For example you are using 6.8.0-41 do you have a 68.8.0-40 or 39 you can select?

@DavidDE post edited to add kernels installed
